# How to make voronoi diagram more random?

Tags: voronoi-diagram

Classical voronoi diagram looks like biology cells. I want to make it more random. Like:

[image] or the one on right (with some roundish borders):

[image]

Is it possible and how?

**P.S.** alternative algorithm suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Voronoi diagrams are a deterministic operation on a set of points and a metric, and you want randomness. The two are incompatible.

Comment: @MorganRodgers yes, sphere regions with random borders (mimic tectonic plates). Not to detailed, so the calculations are fast.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel the points can be placed/moved randomly what is called Jitter and it looks more like what I need, but I want to push it more and get more chaotic forms. Here are some suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/3839131/2703854, but I do not get it.

Comment: Voronoi diagrams inevitably have "straight" edges (think of perpendicular bisectors of two points)

Comment: @Henry maybe you know alternatives to voronoi? Or some mutation of it? As you see in 2nd image it possible to alter the voronoi.

Comment: What if you use a classical voronoi partition (with perhaps smaller partitions, sampling more generator points $p_1,p_2,\dots$ in the space), but in a later step you group some partitions together to form new cells with those non-regular shapes? For each partition you can decide which neighbors to merge in a random fashion.